# Как реализовать смену layout-ов для activity?

Tags: android

Есть активити, которая реализует пошаговый мастер

```
    public void changeStep(CameraStepEvent ev){
        switch (ev.state){

            case TakePhoto:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
                break;
            case SelectBox:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_select_box);
                break;
            case SharePhoto:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_share_photo);
                break;
     }
}
```

На каждом шаге инфлейтится новая разметка. Проблема в том, что если откатываемся на шаг назад и инфлейтим второй раз разметку (к примеру 2 раза R.layout.activity_camera), то активити падает, с ошибкой, что активити уже содержит фрагмент с таким же id.
Можно ли при инфлейте новой разметки полностью удалить иерархию вьюх от старой?
Или тут только в коде добавлять/удалять фрагменты через FragmentManager?

Comment: Я бы может вообще 3 разных активити сделал, так проще делать именно пошаговый мастер. Вы еще подумайте, как восстанавливать в вашем случае состояние активити после выгрузки ее из памяти.

Comment: @RuslanA, да как вариант.

Comment: Так делать как у вас, крайне не рекомендуется, во избежание страшного геморроя и прочих ужасов. Если не хотите на себе испытать всё это - запомните простое правило: одна активти - один `setContentView()`. Нужен новый экран - создавайте новую активити. Вы конечно можете мне сейчас и не поверить и думать, что "как классно я  придумал и почему раньше никто до этого не додумался"  (ха - ха), НО! когда вы поймете, что сотворили, будет уже поздно и в пустую будет потрачено много-много времени. А потом еще переделывать все будете, как у людей сразу принято делать .

Comment: Как вариант можно использовать фрагменты в одной активити, подменяя их по нужному алгоритму. С вашим решением вы еще ничего не сделали и уже ничего не работает, дальше проблем и трудно решаемых дикими костылями ситуаций будет только больше, чем дальше вы будете убеждать себя, что идея то хорошая...

Comment: @pavlofff, да, я в принципе вижу, что фигня выходит, потому и спросил. В общем про setContentView понятно, спасибо